# Stange behavior when increment value

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
$f1  = 1;
$f2  = ++$f1;
$f3  = ++$f2;
$f4  = ++$f3;

echo  $f1 . '<br />'.$f2.'<br />'.$f3.'<br />' .$f4. '<br />';
```

Output is:

```
2
3
4
4
```

I expected $f4 value to be 5, but it is 4. 
What I miss ?

Comment: 4 is correct, you do not ++ $f4.

Comment: on the last line you are actually saying: take $f3's value (which is 3) increment with one ($f3 becomes 4) and assign to $f4 (which will become 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$f1  = 1;
```

Assigns 1 to `$f1`.

```
$f2  = ++$f1;
```

Pre-increments `$f1`. So it is now 2. And this is assigned to `$f2`. Both `$f1` and `$f2` at this point are `2`.

```
$f3  = ++$f2;
```

Pre-increments `$f2`. So it is now 3. And this is assigned to `$f3`. Both `$f2` and `$f3` at this point are `3`.

```
$f4  = ++$f3;
```

Pre-increments `$f4`. So it is now 4. And this is assigned to `$f4`. Both `$f3` and `$f4` at this point are `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The operator ++ actually increments the variable.  What you want is `$fn + 1;`

In the last case $f3 holds 3, is incremented to 4 and 4 is assigned to $f4.

```
$f1 = 1;
$f2  = ++$f1; //both $f1 and $f2 = 2
$f3  = ++$f2; //both = 3
$f4  = ++$f3; //both = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It quite logical, Follow along

$f1  = 1;
The number 1 is assigned to $f1, nothing special here

$f2  = ++$f1;
You pre-increment $f1, so that becomes $f1=2. Then this value is assigned to $f2. So $f=2 also

$f3  = ++$f2;
Here you pre-increment $f2, so $f2 becomes '3', and then you assign that value to $f3. So $f3=3

$f4  = ++$f3;
Next, you pre-increment $f3. Since it was '3', it now becomes '4'. And then that value is assigned to $f4, which also becomes '4'. Thus this leaves you with

2
3
4
4

Answer (score 0):

`$f1` is `1`; you pre-increment it and assign `2` to `$f2`. Same for `3` and `$f3`, `4` and `$f4`. The values match the number the whole way down.

Or, another way: you start with `1`. You have three increment operations. Thus the final result must be `4`.